# Second Navigation on the left side

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, navigation, quick-launch, links-list

How do I add a second navigation on the left side of my page below the quick launch?
Our company is in the process of implementing the new version of sharepoint (2013 foundation) and they would like to add a secondary "quick launch" type navigation under the current one that mirrors/builds on the global navigation. Is there any way to do this? Also they would like to have some of our logos run down the side of our page that link to our external website if possible, which I don't know how to do either. I'm pretty new to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the master page and use Designer Manager to create snippets (Left navigation or Global navigation).

Then put the snippet on your master page (Your desired location)

Comment: We are using sharepoint 2013 foundation so design manager is not available to us.